# how to make a flash effect of a image?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, video, computer-vision

In tensorflow, there is a adjust_brightness API that is quite convenient to augment training data by changing the brightness. My question is how does adjusting to higher brightness different from a real flash? I read a paper that has this augmentation method that adds artificial flash effect to a frame by converting to LUV color space and increasing the intensity by 70%. I am not sure how does this relate to the adjust brightness function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I read a paper that has this augmentation method that adds artificial
>   flash effect to a frame by converting to LUV color space and
>   increasing the intensity by 70%

Though you have not referenced the paper in your question, I think you can do this by converting your RGB image to YUV colorspace using [rgb_to_yuv](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_yuv) and performing [adjust_brightness](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/adjust_brightness) on the Y channel only. The Y channel correlates with the [lightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightness) or the luminance. See [CIELUV color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELUV) for details. So, according to YUV model, by modifying only the Y component in YUV space, you adjust the lightness without affecting the chromaticity.

So now you have the YUV image with the modified Y channel that creates the artificial flash effect. Make sure to clip values that are outside accepted range of Y. Now convert this YUV image back to RGB using [yuv_to_rgb](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/yuv_to_rgb).

`adjust_brightness` operates on all channels of the input image. If you apply this to a color space like the [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space), it will affect both the luminance and chromaticity because they are kind-of correlated with all channels. You can think of YUV as a way of removing this correlation.